# Multiprocessing queue and worker return before closing pool

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, communication

I want to create a number of workers and give them work depending on the received data by the socket. At the same time, I want to return the worker result when he finishes his work, and don't wait until all the workers end.

Is possible to return before closing pool ?

**main.py**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, current_process
import time
import random
import copy_reg
import types
import Extractor as e
import threading


class PageControler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nProcess = 3
        self.pages = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        self.__result = []
        self.manageWork()
        self.extractor = e.Extractor()


    def manageWork(self):

        worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.initPool)
        worker_thread.start()

        work_queue = threading.Thread(target=self.modifyQueue)
        work_queue.start()

    def initPool(self):
        pool = Pool(processes=self.nProcess)

        ti = time.time()
        while (time.time()-ti)<10:
            if self.pages != []:
                pag = self.pages.pop()
                pool.apply_async(self.BarcodeSearcher, args = (pag, ), callback = self.resultCollector)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    def modifyQueue(self):
    """ Simulate socket data receive """    
    ti = time.time()
        while (time.time()-ti)<10:
            time.sleep(4)
            self.pages.append(99)
            print self.pages

    def BarcodeSearcher(self, input_page):        
        print ("Process %s: handling %s" % (current_process(), input_page))  
        result = e.Extractor().BarcodeSearcher(input_page)
        return result

    def resultCollector(self, result):
        self.__result.append(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def _pickle_method(m):
        if m.im_self is None:
            return getattr, (m.im_class, m.im_func.func_name)
        else:
            return getattr, (m.im_self, m.im_func.func_name)

    copy_reg.pickle(types.MethodType, _pickle_method)

    PageControler()
```

**Extractor.py**

```
class Extractor(object):
    """Simulate extractor"""
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def BarcodeSearcher(self,x):
        ti = time.time()
        tf = random.randint(1,4)
        while time.time() - ti < tf:
            random.uniform(1., 2.)
        return tf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your callback function will return the results as soon as worker is done with it, before the pool has been closed.

so to get the results you can just poll your __result to see if you got any new ones.

just make sure you do it in thread that's not waiting, which will be your main thread in this case.

```
last_results_len = 0
while True: # or whatever you choose to..
    results_len = len(__result)
    if results_len != last_results_len:
        last_results_len += 1  # add one so you get them all in case they come in quick
        print(__result[results_len - 1]) # whatever you want to do here

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I have overlooked that. Thanks for your help!